# Match input with multiple attributes selector

Tags: javascript

I have an input element:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='abc' />
```

How can I select it with querySelector using both attributes?

I have tried the following query:

```
input[name="abc", type="checkbox"]
```

But unfortunately an error appeared:

> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on...

Comment: post all relevant code please...

Comment: Your code is a selector, rather than actual javascript. Could you perhaps put together a complete, minimal example?

Comment: Sorry for the answer, understood the quetsion wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose each individual property/attribute with it's own square brackets.

```
input[name="abc"][type="checkbox"]
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="abc"]'));
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='abc' />
```